# Optimizing a query (Sorting)

Tags: mysql

There is a long query I would like to optimize but I can't find the way to do it.

The thing is say you have a table called Results_Race, this table's columns are:

```
<I filled it with some sample data to make it more clear>
----------------------------------
|Driver name| Position | Race id |
----------------------------------
|Hamilton   | 1        | 00001   |
|Hamilton   | 2        | 00002   |
|Alonso     | 1        | 00002   |
|Alonso     | 2        | 00001   |
| ...       | ...      | ...     |
----------------------------------
```

Driver names are varchar, Positions are number and race id is number too

Say you need to sort all the drivers based on their finishing places, so the first pilot after sorting would be the one who has most 1st places. In case of a draw, say Hamilton and Alonso both have five 1st places (given under the position column), you would need to evaluate who has most 2nd places, but imagine there is draw there too, then we evaluate whom of the two has most 3rd places, and so on...

I suppose this is possible, I just cant figure it out, anyone can shed some light on this please?

My current query is a mess by the way, to summarize this is what my query looks like:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS POS1,V.DRIVER DV FROM RESULTS_RACE V WHERE V.POSITION=1 GROUP BY DV) G1 ON (G1.DV=A.DRIVER)

LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS POS2,V.DRIVER DV FROM RESULTS_RACE V WHERE V.POSITION=2 GROUP BY DV) G2 ON (G2.DV=A.DRIVER)
```

.
.
.

POS1 is the number of first places
POS2 is the number of second places
and so on
Driver is the name of the pilot

I have 34 queries like this, one for each position, then at the end I have an order by which sorts the drivers properly:

```
ORDER BY POS1 DESC,POS2 DESC, ... ,POS34 DESC
```

Comment: Post the whole query, not just your `LEFT JOIN`s

Comment: You could probably use a `sum(case when` type structure as a column rather than joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works with undefined number of positions:

```
select driver_name, group_concat(lpad(c, 10, 0) order by position) order_col
from (
  select driver_name, position, count(r.position) as c
  from (select distinct driver_name from result_race) d
  cross join (select distinct position from result_race) p
  left join result_race r using(driver_name, position)
  group by d.driver_name, p.position
) sub
group by driver_name
order by group_concat(lpad(c, 10, 0) order by position) desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c8786/1

Comment: Today im already too tired but I'll be sure to check your answer in my environment tomorrow because I think you solved the biggest problem I had which were the number of positions ! If it works better i'll be sure to mark your answer as the solution! Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f25336/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    Driver_name, 
    SUM(IF(Position = 1,1,0)) POS1,
    SUM(IF(Position = 2,1,0)) POS2,
    SUM(IF(Position = 3,1,0)) POS3
FROM X
GROUP BY 
    Driver_name
ORDER BY 
    POS1 DESC,
    POS2 DESC,
    POS3 DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f25336/2/0)**:

```
| Driver_name | POS1 | POS2 | POS3 |
|-------------|------|------|------|
|    Hamilton |    2 |    2 |    0 |
|      Alonso |    1 |    2 |    1 |
```

Comment: This is a very clean answer but I think Paul's fits better cause if I understand correctly in your answer I would need 34 SUMS (because I have 34 positions), Paul's answer does it with undefined number of positions which I think is more appropiate, thank you for your answer anyways!